# Build & Minify & Prefix CSS in one go with npm

Tags: npm, sass, postcss, npm-scripts

I have a `build` script for building CSS like this:

```json
"prebuild:css": "node-sass --source-map true sass/styles.scss /styles.prebuild.css",
"prefix:css": "postcss --use autoprefixer -b 'last 2 versions' < /aareguru.styles.css | postcss --use cssnano > /styles.min.css",
"build": "npm run prebuild:css && npm run prefix:css"
```

1. First a prebuilt vanilla css file is created.
2. Then autoprefixes are applied
3. And lastly Minification is applied

Is it possible to do this in one go?

Because if the prebuild somehow fails the script is no longer in sync and will fail.

Comment: You could switch to something like `Gulp` to make this process easier to manage and catch out errors etc... The questions is, if one fails, why would you still want the other to run?

Comment: And `Gulp` is allowing to do this in one go?

Comment: Yes, you can chain gulp, so it would look like `gulp.src( [fileArray] ).pipe( sass() ).pipe( autoprefix() ).pipe( minify() ).pipe( uglify() )` or something. But if one fails, the rest of the process will obviously also fail since every next task relies on the last. So to reiterate my question: if one fails, why would you still want the rest to run? Your output would be incorrect anyway, and without errors or messages you wouldn't even really know that your output doesn't work correctly, making you more prone to mistakes.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone looking for a quick, ready to use code:

Run these commands:

```
npm install -D gulp-sass
npm install -D gulp-autoprefixer
npm install -D gulp-uglifycss
```

Then create a gulpfile.js with this code:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var sass = require('gulp-sass');
var autoprefixer = require('gulp-autoprefixer');
var uglifycss = require('gulp-uglifycss');

var paths = {
    source : './assets/*.sass',
    destination: './css'
};

gulp.task('sass', () => {
    return gulp.src(paths.source)
    .pipe(sass().on('error', sass.logError))
    .pipe(autoprefixer())
    .pipe(uglifycss({
        "maxLineLen": 80,
        "uglyComments": true
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.destination));
});
```

Run

```
gulp sass
```